# Update file number from file name using exiftool

Tags: bash, exif, exiftool

I'm clicking photos on a camera (Fuji x100s) that doesn't store the `filenumber` tag in the exif. Though it adds this information in the file name, eg, `DSCF0488.JPG`, `DSCF0489.JPG`, `DSCF0490.JPG`.

How do I extract this number and set it as the file number?

Comment: Could you be more specific about the tool you are using and perhaps give an example of how it should be called? What system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the numbers from the files in your example, using native bash regex, you could do something like this:

```
for i in *.JPG; do 
    [[ $i =~ ([[:digit:]]+) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
done
```

Running that loop from the directory containing the files in your question would give the output:

```
0488
0489
0490
```

So if you have a tool called `exif_script` that can add this information to your files, you could do something like:

```
for photo in *.JPG; do 
    if [[ $photo =~ ([[:digit:]]+) ]]; then
        file_number="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        exif_script # set number to $file_number
    fi
done
```

If you don't have a new enough bash to support regular expression matching, you could use sed:

```
for i in *.JPG; do file_number=$(echo "$i" | sed 's/[^0-9]\{1,\}\([0-9]\{1,\}\).JPG/\1/'); done
```

The value of `$file_number` will be the same as in the first piece of code but this approach should work on the vast majority of platforms.